# Getting multiple values by passing a key in redis cache

Tags: c#, .net-core, redis

I am using Redis cache from `StackExchange.Redis.`

How can i retrieve set of values if a key contains the specified string.

For example,

1. Key:  "User:1"
   Value: "User 1 Details"
2. Key: "User:2"
   Value: "User 2 Details"

I want to get list of users by passing a key value.
something like sending `user` as key like that.

Currently my code to set key value is below,

`// _redis is IRedisCacheClient from StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core.Abstractions`

`_redis.Db0.Add("user:1", user);`

Any suggestions/help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of research for a while sharing knowledge here. The list of users can be retrieved by passing key like this `"user:*"`

Example,

> Key: `"user:1"` with Value: "User1 object"
>
> Key: `"user:2"` with Value: "User2 object"

The key to get list of users will be `"user:*"`